# Why are Pipelines used as part of GridsearchCV and not the other way around?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

Though I understand the potential benefits, especially in combination with `GridSearchCV`, I wonder why it is always used like this (or at least from how I understand it):

> Pipeline steps are set for each classifier (with `'passthrough'` for the `clf` step). Then, `GridSearchCV` equips the pipeline with multiple parameters and classifiers.

I am not sure if this is true, but from my point of view, it seems as if this causes the steps **before** the classifier to run multiple times, even if they are always used with the same parameter.

This leads me to the question, why it is not used the other way around... or if this would even be possible?

Here is a picture of the situation in my head with example configuration:
[image: pipe-grid vs. grid-pipe]

Comment: You can use 'passthrough' to specify multiple alternative objects (reducers, classifiers etc) at any stage in the pipeline. See here for how to specify multiple reducers, you should be able to adapt this to multiple classifiers:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_compare_reduction.html

Answer (score 0):

First let's create a dataset

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV


# generate some data to play with
X, y = make_classification(n_informative=5, n_redundant=0, random_state=42)
```

Now the usual way of working with a grid_search is to try **different parameters for all steps**.
As an example let's use `PCA` and `SVC`.

```py
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca', PCA()), ('svm', svm.SVC())])

# Parameters of pipelines can be set using ‘__’ separated parameter names:
param_grid = {
    'pca__n_components': [5, 15, 30, 45, 64],
    'svm__C': [1, 5, 10],
}
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

However if you want you can apply the previous steps to the classifier itself and only perform the `GridSearch` on the classifier:

```py
pca = PCA()
X_pca, y_pca = pca.fit_transform(X, y)

parameters = {'C':[1, 5, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC()
gs = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters)

gs.fit(X_pca, y_pca)
```

The problem is that this way you can't test parameter correlations between different steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this explains pretty good how pipelines work together with gridsearch. However, it does not really answer why it cannot be different, as I explained in the diagram I attached (one pipeline, triggering a grid of classifiers).